# Binding button style to a variable android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a variable in my app that symbolizes a state..

I want the button's UI to change, regarding the value of the variable.

For example:

variable = 1 --> button = green

variable = 2 --> button = red

I know there is xml file that can change UI based on clicking, but I don't think it handles my scenario

Thanks :)

Comment: only 2 variables are there for change state condition is it dynamic??

Comment: Actually one - boolean. but that's not the point..the question is not about specific implementation - more about a binding idea between logic and UI

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
private void buttonBgBasedOnVariable(int variable){
   if(variable == 1){
        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
   }else if(variable == 2){
        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi..Thanks for your answer, but my example was quite simple..The idea behind the binding is the interesting thing..I actually want to change a lot more..I don't think this way is scalable enough..What if I change the variable at several places in my code? Do I have to write a listener to the variable..Seems a lot of work for a simple bind : )

Comment: Call the above method when the variable is changed!!

Comment: Good solution if both variable and button are on the same class...........There is a great separation between logic and UI (well..trying to...)

Comment: Or else pass the variable to the method.

Comment: Which method? Logic classes don't have any knowledge on UI classes..I can't just call updateButton method..Thought there is a smart mechanism to solve such binding problem : /